# while creating NextJs app page directory is not availabe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am beginner at NextJs and when I install next [here is image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2SF8.png) using command "yarn create next-app" it create my app but problem is it does not have page directory what should I do now please help me...

I am trying to building NextJs app but in NextJs app Page directory is not available

Comment: Restart the project creation phase. The terminal will ask you at one time if you want to use the `app` directory, which obviously you did. If you want to use the `pages` folder, answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey in Nextjs 13 you will have `app directory` or `src/app directory` to handle routing and create your application.

Basic Introduction -
You might now have app/layout.js and app/page.js

- Layout file is the default layout for all the pages you create
- page.js is your main page 
  Further if you want to create more routes example localhost:3000/login
- Your folder structure will look something like
  app/login/page.js
- Another example for /register i.e localhost:3000/register
  app/register/page.js

> ```
> page.js is the main entry point for any route
> ```

For details/reference - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration

Comment: Pages directory is NOT deprecated in Next 13. Source - https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4#is-the-pages-router-going-away

Comment: @IgorDanchenko My bad yea its not deprecated, in next13 you get app directory to handle routing

Answer (score 0):

@Neeraj already answer your question but the pages directory is not the only change on the last version of NextJS, server side components are stable on this version... This last version need a new code structure and read new docs.

If you are on a rush to create new project with existing knowledge about NextJS, you need to create a NextJS project with old versions (like 13.1.2 where App directory was experimental yet):
`npx create-next-app@13.1.2 panda1` and **inside** panda1 folder: `npm i next@13.1.2`. This is because you can't install specific version using npx, you need to override it with the old version install.

Don't forget to delete the caret (^) on the `next` dependency on package.json (to prevent accidental updates on version)